# Richfacess Calendar | Month Picker | Data Not Submitted

Tags: jsf, datepicker, calendar, richfaces

I am trying to use the Richfaces Calendar as a Month Picker instead of a Date Picker. Though the below code tags display the Month Picker as expected but the value of selected month and year is not submitted to the Backing Bean.

-----XHTML TAGs ----

```
<rich:calendar id="fromDate"
                currentDate="#{numberManagementController.searchCriteria.fromDate}"
                value="#{numberManagementController.searchCriteria.fromDate}"
                showWeekDaysBar="false" datePattern="MMM-yyyy" showFooter="false"
                popup="false" enableManualInput="false" showInput="false"
                styleClass="numberMonthSelector" popupClass="numberCalendarPopup"
                oncurrentdateselect="event.rf.component.__selectDate(event.rf.data)" />



<rich:calendar id="toDate" showWeekDaysBar="false" showFooter="false"
                    currentDate="#{numberManagementController.searchCriteria.toDate}"
                    value="#{numberManagementController.searchCriteria.toDate}"
                    oncurrentdateselect="event.rich.component.selectDate(event.rich.date)"
                    popup="false" styleClass="numberMonthSelector" popupClass="numberCalendarPopup"/>
```

-----CSS -------

```
.numberMonthSelector tr[id$="CalendarDateEditorLayoutTR"]
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .numberCalendarPopup tr[id]{
        display:none;
    }
```

Please help me out, stuck on the issue for couple of days.

Initial help was taken from [here](http://in.relation.to/12480.lace)

Richfaces - 4.1.0.Final

Many Thanks
Sachin Jain

Comment: removing the value parameter worked for me from the first tag given in the question above. the value `oncurrentdateselect="event.rich.component.selectDate(event.rich.date)" `does not work for Richfaces 4

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<a4j:ajax>` if you want to send a value to a bean in response to some event.

```
<rich:calendar id="fromDate"
               currentDate="#{numberManagementController.searchCriteria.fromDate}"
               value="#{numberManagementController.searchCriteria.fromDate}"
               showWeekDaysBar="false" datePattern="MMM-yyyy" showFooter="false"
               popup="false" enableManualInput="false" showInput="false"
               styleClass="numberMonthSelector" popupClass="numberCalendarPopup">
    <a4j:ajax event="currentdateselect" 
              onbeforesubmit="event.rf.component.__selectDate(event.rf.data)" 
              execute="@this"/>
</rich:calendar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will give it a try, though I solved the problem by removing the value parameter

Comment: If you remove @value how are you getting the date into the bean then?

Comment: Once the user selects a month and year it gets set into the backing bean using the xurrentDate attribute of the tag